# How can I get Emacs 21-style file-name completion in GNU Emacs 25.1.1?

Tags: key-bindings, completion, keymap, filenames, emacs25

How can I make file-name completion in GNU Emacs 25.1.1 act like it did in version 21.x.x?

There are a few things that bother me:

1. The `*Completions*` buffer opens up in a custom fit-to-content window. It used to open in a half-size window.
2. I have to hit `<TAB> <TAB>` to get the `*Completions*` buffer. It used to be a single `<SPC>`. There is an intervening `Complete, but not unique` message I would like to eliminate too.
3. I have to hit `<TAB>` to get a completion instead of `<SPC>`.

Is there a way to fix all these at once?
If not, are there specific customizations are code fragments that would restore the older behavior?

Comment: The minibuffer completion maps changed quite a bit. You'll need to do some archaeology. As for TAB and completion, you might try different values for option `completion-auto-help`, but I doubt that any of the 3 values will really give you what you want. Hopefully someone will have a good answer for you.

Comment: So, for example during `find-file`, TAB is bound to `minibuffer-complete`. Remapping that to SPC might get what you want. The major-mode of the minibuffer is `minibuffer-inactive-mode`. Its docs and maybe the rest of _minibuffer.el_ might be helpful. You might have to rewrite or advise whatever function is printing the "Complete, but not unique" message.

Comment: Changing the size of the window holding the `*Completions*` buffer could probably done in `temp-buffer-show-hook` (my first choice), or maybe `completion-list-mode-hook`.

Comment: You also might want to checkout `completion-auto-help` for 1 vs 2 TABs behavior